# node.js using function from another js file

Tags: node.js

How to use the function from another js file .

example:

The master.js file contain the following code.

```
 if(typeof(CONVERTER) == "undefined") var CONVERTER = {};
    (function(_e) {
      "use strict";
      var synmonth = 29.530588853;     //synodic month (new Moon to new Moon)
      var ptsa = new Array(485, 203, 199, 14, 12, 12, 12, 9, 8)
      var ptsb = new Array(324.96, 337.23,320.81, 227.73, 15.45)
      var ptsc = new Array(1934.136, 4777.259, 1222.114, 16859.074)

    function GetAdjusted(yea,mx,dx){
    .......
     return(result);
    }

      _e.GetAdjusted = function(yea,mx,dx) {
        return GetAdjusted(yea,mx,dx);
      };
    }(CONVERTER));
```

How to use/declare the function in another js file using node.js

Comment: `require` the module. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: I'm getting an error TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'GetAdjusted'.  But if I deploy above code in web base is working fine.

Comment: You are probably not creating the module correctly. Did you follow the examples in the link?

Comment: The module created by another developer. I'm just a user. But I don't see any "exports" keyword in the master.js,  Does it means the code ONLY suitable use in web not for node.js ?

Comment: Hi;  Felix Kling, Thanks. By adding the "module.exports.GetAdjusted=GetAdjusted" solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably extracted from a Frontend module.
Assuming you want to use the  getAdjusted function which have CONVERTER as dependency. You can write as following:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(CONVERTER){
  if(typeof(CONVERTER) == "undefined"){
    CONVERTER = {};  
  } 
  var synmonth = 29.530588853;     //synodic month (new Moon to new Moon)
  var ptsa = new Array(485, 203, 199, 14, 12, 12, 12, 9, 8);
  var ptsb = new Array(324.96, 337.23,320.81, 227.73, 15.45);
  var ptsc = new Array(1934.136, 4777.259, 1222.114, 16859.074);

  var getAdjusted = function getAdjusted(yea,mx,dx){
   // your code here
   return(result);
  };

  return getAdjusted;
};
```

In order to use it from another file

```
//Assuming your CONVERTER object exists and pass it into require
var getAdjusted = require("/path/to/your/file")(CONVERTER);

// use it. Assuming yea, mx, dx exists.
getAdjusted(yea,mx,dx);
```

Comment: I don't understand what does the (CONVERTER) mean at the end of the require statement